# Convert nested json object into another json object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, nested

I've been playing with json objects & using ReactJS. One of the json object represented by variable 'res'. How do I convert 'res' into 'b'. I'm also getting my json object 'res' from an api.

I've reciprocated my problem over this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-leaf-sznhx?file=/src/App.js

```
const [res, setResult] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries").then(response => {
        setResult(response.data);
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```

How do I convert this:

```
const res = 
{
  "0": {
    "id": "1",
    "countryInfo": [
      {
        "_id": "4",
        "lat": "33"
      }
    ]
  },
  "1": {
    "id": "2",
    "countryInfo": [
      {
        "_id": "8",
        "lat": "41"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

into this json object:

```
const b =

{
  "popup": {
    "countryInfo": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "lat": "33"
      },
      {
        "_id": "2",
        "lat": "41"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to just update the keys from your previous question, so instead of having `menuitem` you'll have `countryInfo`, check my answer below and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @LuísRamalho I'm getting error: can't convert undefined to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want an identical solution to your previous question, something like:

```js
const res = {
  "0": {
    id: "1",
    countryInfo: [{
      _id: "4",
      lat: "33",
    }, ],
  },
  "1": {
    id: "2",
    countryInfo: [{
      _id: "8",
      lat: "41",
    }, ],
  },
};

let b = Object.keys(res).reduce(
  (p, c) => {
    for (let item of res[c].countryInfo) {
      p.popup.countryInfo.push(item);
    }
    return p;
  }, {
    popup: {
      countryInfo: [],
    },
  }
);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: can't convert undefined to object

Comment: @KillMe, I've fixed your sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-monad-fli3m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Basically, you cannot give the `countryInfo` object to `MaterialTable`, you'll have to destructure the properties you want from it.